# how to print the value instead of id in xls file with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xls

I m using PHP Mysql.i submit a form and fetch the data into a table format in my page.now i want that the user can download the xls file from that table but my problem is that in my database table few values are in id form how can i retrieve them in xls file coz in xls file its showing id's as there are id's in databse table.i dont want to submit the values as name coz name can be more than one.

here is my download xls link code:

```
<span style="float:right;"><a href="customer_xls.php" type="button" class="btn">Download XLS</a></span>
```

and here is the customer_xls.php file:

```
<?php
     //EDIT YOUR MySQL Connection Info:
     $DB_Server = "localhost";        //your MySQL Server 
     $DB_Username = "root";                 //your MySQL User Name 
     $DB_Password = "";                //your MySQL Password 
     $DB_DBName = "xyz";                //your MySQL Database Name 
     $DB_TBLName = "customers";                //your MySQL Table Name 
    // $term = $_REQUEST['term'];

     //$DB_TBLName,  $DB_DBName, may also be commented out & passed to the browser
     //as parameters in a query string, so that this code may be easily reused for
     //any MySQL table or any MySQL database on your server
     //DEFINE SQL QUERY:
     //you can use just about ANY kind of select statement you want - 
     //edit this to suit your needs!
     $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
    //die();
     //Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
     //for when file was generated:
     //set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
     $Use_Title = 1;
     //define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
     $now_date = date('m-d-Y H:i');
     //define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
     $title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";

     /*
     Leave the connection info below as it is:
     just edit the above.
     (Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
     */
     //create MySQL connection
     $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
         or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     //select database
     $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
         or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     //execute query
     $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)
         or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     //if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
     //if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
     if (isset($w) && ($w==1))
     {
         $file_type = "msword";
         $file_ending = "doc";
     }else {
         $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
         $file_ending = "xls";
     }
     //header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
     header("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$DB_TBLName.$file_ending");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     header("Expires: 0");
     /*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */
     if (isset($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
     {
         /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
         //create title with timestamp:
         if ($Use_Title == 1)
         {
             echo("$titlenn");
         }
         //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
         $sep = "\r"; //new line character
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {
             //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
             $schema_insert = "";
             for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
             {
             //define field names
             $field_name = mysql_field_name($result,$j);
             //will show name of fields
             $schema_insert .= "$field_name:t";
                 if(!isset($row[$j])) {
                     $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                     }
                 elseif ($row[$j] != "") {
                     $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                     }
                 else {
                     $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                     }
             }
             $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
             $schema_insert .= "\t\n";
             print(trim($schema_insert));
             //end of each mysql row
             //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row

             print "n----------------------------------------------------n";
         }
     }else{

         /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
         //create title with timestamp:
         if ($Use_Title == 1)
         {
             echo("$titlen");
         }
         //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
         $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
         //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
         for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)
         {
             echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
         }
         print("\n");
         //end of printing column names
         //start while loop to get data
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {
             //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
             $schema_insert = "";
             for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
             {
                 if(!isset($row[$j]))
                     $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                     $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 else
                     $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
             }
             //$schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
             //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
             //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain n or r
             //these two characters are now replaced with a space
             //$schema_insert = preg_replace("/rn|nr|n|r/", " ", $schema_insert);
             $schema_insert .= "\n\t";
             print(trim($schema_insert));
             print "\n\r";


         }
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join your basic table with tables that contains word representation of the id's saved in first table. Example:

```
Table A:
id | id_user | id_city
1  | 10      | 5

Table B:
id | user_name
10 | Michael

Table C:
id | city_name
5  | New York
```

For that tables you should build query like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.user_name, c.city_name FROM table_a a 
JOIN table_b b ON a.id_user = b.id JOIN
JOIN table_c c ON a.id_city = c.id
```

Result of that query should look like this:

```
1 | Michael | New York
```

The other way to get same results is to build subqueries (but this is much more time-consuming than JOIN method). Example:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT user_name FROM table_b WHERE id = a.id_user) name, 
(SELECT city_name FROM table_c WHERE id = a.id_city) city FROM table_a a
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply bro but as u can see i m using seperate xls.php file to download the exl as the user click on download xls link and its take him to xls.php file and from select query i m fetching the data from that particular table and in xls.php file the $result gives us the values in xls file with select query on that page so how can i join here??

Comment: @Monty: Just change your query here: $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName" like I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks bro.finaly after 2 hours i have done it.thaanks for ur precious help.